# Generate raml from example json response

Tags: json, rest, documentation-generation, raml

I just learned about [RAML - RESTful API modeling language](http://raml.org/) and it seems quite useful. I have some endpoints that return json. Is there any tool or code out there to **generate RAML** from one or more example JSON responses?

I've seen tools to generate from RAML, but none that create the RAML itself. My main motivation is just to quickly get up and running with RAML for all of my endpoints, which would be a bit onerous to do by hand (and we're programmers, so of course we're going to automate it).

Comment: Have you checked the Swagger-to-RAML or JAXRS-to-RAML plugins? They seem to be able to produce RAML out of the implementation.

Comment: But I strongly suggest you go the other way around: create your RAML and JSON schema first, then generate artifacts from it. The spec, being a public contract, should be stable and drive the dance, not the implementation. Otherwise, a seemingly benign code refactoring may completely change the RAML/JSON Schema specs, breaking the public contract of the API.

Comment: @DavidDossot the point is to get up and running quickly with an existing implementation. Once we're there, of course we'd drive with RAML. I haven't looked much into Swagger- or JAXRS-to-RAML because we're not using either of those, but maybe there's a way to do JSON-to-Swagger or JAXRS and then convert to RAML...